# Merge multiple Personal.xlsb

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, merge

There are [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28160286/256431) and [SU](https://superuser.com/q/662008/39835) answers for merging the contents of spreadsheets, but has anyone merged VBA macros to only keep distinct macros and/or highlight differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One roundabout way would be to save all macros for each spreadsheet to corresponding text files and compare the same using diff/merge [utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org).

If you have a large number of spreadsheets then [this VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49773) or [this VBScript](http://www.pretentiousname.com/excel_extractvba/index.html) will help reduce manual labour.

There's also a purpose-built VBA diff utility called [VbaDiff](http://www.vbadiff.com) you can try that "will mark modules that have code changes in red and modules that are not in both projects in blue":

[image: 1]

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. That was the approach I saw, but I've accumulated 16 of them :-( I do expect only two or three have different details, but which ones is still a bit hard to do manually.

Comment: Unless there's some sort of diff/merge utility that understands the XLSB format (and I don't think MS has ever described the binary format properly) and can compare the text directly, you might not have a choice. One way I can think of to reduce effort would be to write yet another macro or a stand-alone VBScript that iterates through all the files and does the work of extracting the macro code for you to diff/merge. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/49773) or [this](http://www.pretentiousname.com/excel_extractvba/index.html) for example.

Comment: FYI I've used the second link from your comment, with WinMerge, if you want to add that to your answer. I just had to "Trust access to the VBA project object model" in Trust Center > Macro Settings (and perhaps "Enable all macros", which I did just in case). Of course, I have remembered to restore these settings afterwards :-)