# How to combine data from multiple sheets into 1 main sheet in calc

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, combine

I have an excel file which gets generated from various database servers on fly by executing sql. Separate sheet gets generated for each server. Now I simply want to combine data of all sheets. Each sheet has same number of columns and headings. In combined sheet heading should appear at top only once.

For e.g
North sheet

Sales Person | Item | Quantity | Sales |
James | Ball | 100 | 2000|
Jack | Bat | 50 | 100 |
James | Bat | 25 | 50 |

South sheet
Sales Person | Item | Quantity | Sales |
Sara | Racket | 100 | 2000|
Lucy | Ball | 50 | 100 |
Sara | Racket | 25 | 50 |

Combined sheet

Sales Person | Item | Quantity | Sales |
James | Ball | 100 | 2000|
Jack | Bat | 50 | 100 |
James | Bat | 25 | 50 |
Sara | Racket | 100 | 2000|
Lucy | Ball | 50 | 100 |
Sara | Racket | 25 | 50 |

Comment: Hi Prajakta, can you add a question to your question please? I'm afraid we won't be able to help you if we don't know what you need, and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The [How can I merge hundreds of Excel spreadsheet files?](https://superuser.com/questions/304899/how-can-i-merge-hundreds-of-excel-spreadsheet-files) post describes how you can do this in Excel. You can probably use this in Calc as well.