# Merging all Data into one sheet with their respective sheet name in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel file with near about 80 sheets. what i want is to merge in one sheet with their sheet name in column like this

[image]

Any Workaround for this task...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge hundreds of Excel spreadsheet files?](http://superuser.com/questions/304899/how-can-i-merge-hundreds-of-excel-spreadsheet-files)

Comment: [RDBMerge, Excel Merge Add-in for Excel for Windows](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm)

Comment: @Rob: Seems promising but where is download links..?

Comment: Was me that posted, not Rob ;) Did you scroll to the bottom of the page? "Download

Note: Download the add-in that is correct for your Excel version, If you want a Mac version of the add-in check out the Mac section on my website." etc, links follow.

Comment: Ah Sorry ..! Thanks for help DavidPostill..!