# Batch command to combine multiple excel files into an excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have many excel files. i want to combine them into a single file with multiple excel sheets. Is there a batch command to combine multiple excel files into an excel file with multiple sheets?

Comment: This shall involve the Excel program itself, likely.

Comment: Example of such code in excel:  http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/import-sheets.html

Comment: Possibly helpful/duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/304899/how-can-i-merge-hundreds-of-excel-spreadsheet-files/305532#305532 (although this is VBa, not batch)

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).